Enable OnClick on AdornmentText in MudBlazor
<MudTextField AdornmentColor="Color.Primary" AdornmentText="AText"  OnAdornmentClick="AdornmentChange" Margin="Margin.Dense" Adornment="Adornment.End" ReadOnly="rt.AutoWidth" @bind-Value="rt.width"  Label="Width" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />

How can I enable the onclick on Adornment text. I just click on Adornment text and the text changed
 <MudTextField AdornmentColor="Color.Primary" AdornmentText="@AText"  OnAdornmentClick="AdornmentChange" Margin="Margin.Dense" Adornment="Adornment.End" ReadOnly="rt.AutoWidth" @bind-Value="rt.width"  Label="Width" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />

I have tried this code but it's not work

Adornment Text isn't clickable.  You need to use an Adornment Icon.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true">Hello, world!</MudText>
<MudText Class="mb-8">Welcome to your new app, powered by MudBlazor and the .NET 8 Template!</MudText>

<MudAlert Severity="Severity.Normal">
    You can find documentation and examples on our website here:
    <MudLink Href="https://mudblazor.com" Target="_blank" Typo="Typo.body2" Color="Color.Primary">
        <b>www.mudblazor.com</b>
    </MudLink>
</MudAlert>

<MudTextField AdornmentColor="Color.Primary"
              AdornmentText="Hello"
              OnAdornmentClick="this.AdornmentChange"
              Margin="Margin.Dense"
              Adornment="Adornment.End"
              @bind-Value="_value"
              Label="Width"
              Variant="Variant.Outlined" />

<MudTextField AdornmentColor="Color.Primary"
              AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Custom.Brands.MudBlazor"
              OnAdornmentClick="this.AdornmentChange"
              Margin="Margin.Dense"
              Adornment="Adornment.End"
              @bind-Value="_value"
              Label="Width"
              Variant="Variant.Outlined" />

<MudAlert Severity="Severity.Info">@_message</MudAlert>

@code {
    private string? _value;
    private string _message = $"Loaded at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";

    private Task AdornmentChange()
    {
        _message = $"Clicked at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

The relevant Mud code is the MudInputAdornment component:
<div class="@Class">
    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text))
    {
        <MudText Color="@Color" tabindex="-1">@Text</MudText>
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Icon))
    {
        @if (AdornmentClick.HasDelegate)
        {
            <MudIconButton Class="mud-input-adornment-icon-button" Icon="@Icon" OnClick="@AdornmentClick" Edge="@Edge" Size="@Size" Color="@Color" aria-label="@AriaLabel" tabindex="-1" />
        }
        else
        {
            <MudIcon Class="mud-input-adornment-icon" Icon="@Icon" Size="@Size" Color="@Color" aria-label="@AriaLabel" tabindex="-1" />
        }
    }
</div>


There is an issue i have to use toggle text or icon like "%" or "px". There is an % icon in mudblazor but not px icon so that why i have to use adornment icon.

Don's shoot the messenger!  Because that's the way the component is coded.  Write your own if that's what you want.
